# xsl convert / translate template

Tags: xslt

I am creating an xsl-fo to rtf style sheet. One of the problems I have is to convert the numerous units of measure in a xsl-fo document to twips (rtf unit of measure).

One particular piece of code caluclates the widths of the columns:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(preceding-sibling:
   :fo:table-column/@column-width) + @column-width"/>
```

...problem being the value of `/@column-width` could be anything from `1in`(1 inch) to `20px`(20 pixels), so when I do the sum it will fail.

I need to somehow convert `@column-width` to a twip equivelant:
`1pt = 19.95 twips, 1px = 15 twips, 1pc = 240 twips, 1in = 1440 twips, 1cm = 567 twips, 1mm = 56.7 twips, 1em = 240 twips`

I can probably write a method that can do the conversion, but I am convinced there is some way to make use of the `translate()` function to do this much more efficiantly.

Please take note that my xsl is not all that great, so an example of how to achieve this will be appreciated

**EDIT**

I managed to find something I want, but have no idea how to call this template from the above calculation:

```
<xsl:template match="@*" mode="convert-to-twips">
    <xsl:variable name="scaling-factor">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains (., 'pt')">19.95</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains (., 'px')">15</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains (., 'pc')">240</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains (., 'in')">1440</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains (., 'cm')">567</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains (., 'mm')">56.7</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains (., 'em')">240</xsl:when>
        <!-- guess: 1em = 12pt -->
        <xsl:otherwise>1</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="numeric-value"
         select="translate (., '-0123456789.ptxcinme', '-0123456789.')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$numeric-value * $scaling-factor"/>

 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and easy solution.

Comment: Yes, and this is a *complete* solution -- not just pseudo-code.

Comment: My answer wants to be just an example of how you can use your template rule using `xsl:call-template`. There is also a little mistake in how you are using `translate`. See my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
 xmlns:fo="some:fo" xmlns:my="my:my" >
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <my:units>
  <unit name="pt">19.95</unit>
  <unit name="in">1440</unit>
  <unit name="cm">567</unit>
  <unit name="mm">56.7</unit>
  <unit name="em">240</unit>
  <unit name="px">15</unit>
  <unit name="pc">240</unit>
 </my:units>

 <xsl:variable name="vUnits" select=
      "document('')/*/my:units/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*/*/@column-width"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@column-width">
  <xsl:variable name="vQuantity" select=
      "substring(.,1, string-length() -2)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vUnit" select=
      "substring(., string-length() -1)"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vrtfAccumWidth">
   <num>0</num>
   <xsl:for-each select=
     "../preceding-sibling::fo:table-column/@column-width">
    <xsl:variable name="vQ" select=
      "substring(.,1, string-length() -2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vU" select=
      "substring(., string-length() -1)"/>

     <num>
      <xsl:value-of select=
       "$vQ * $vUnits[@name=$vU]"/>
     </num>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:value-of select=
  "$vQuantity * $vUnits[@name=$vUnit]
  +
   sum(ext:node-set($vrtfAccumWidth)/num)
  "/>

  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document (as none was provided!):**

```
<fo:fo xmlns:fo="some:fo">
 <fo:table>
  <fo:table-column column-width="2pt"/>
  <fo:table-column column-width="2in"/>
  <fo:table-column column-width="2cm"/>
  <fo:table-column column-width="2mm"/>
  <fo:table-column column-width="2em"/>
  <fo:table-column column-width="2px"/>
  <fo:table-column column-width="2pc"/>
 </fo:table>
</fo:fo>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
39.9
2919.9
4053.9
4167.3
4647.3
4677.3
5157.3
```

**Notice**: If a more efficient solution is needed for a big sequence of `fo:table-column\@column-width`, then the **[FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net)** - **[`scanl`](http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/func-scanl.xsl?revision=1.1&view=markup)** template/function can be used -- see my answer to your previous question for a complete code example.

Comment: @Flynn1179: My arithmetic *is* correct and sometimes what may seem easy could "easily" turn out to be incorrect :)

Comment: Yeah, I'd already noticed that and deleted my comment; I misread the question where it said the point was to calculate the width of the columns, thinking it wasn't supposed to be cumulative.

Comment: @Flynn1179: No problem, mate. We are all human beings and are supposed to err at least sometimes :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this template to make use of the existing one you have:

```
<xsl:template match="@column-width">
  <xsl:variable name="previous">
    0<xsl:apply-templates select="../preceding-sibling::*[1]/@column-width" />
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="this">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="convert-to-twips"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="$previous + $this" />
</xsl:template>
```

It's fairly straightforward as you can see, simply calculating the width of previous columns, then adding it to the current one. You'll probably notice there's a 0 in front of the `<xsl:apply-templates` instruction in the first variable; that's to make sure that a valid number is given to the variable. If there are no previous columns, then it'll store '0' instead of ''.

Strictly speaking, you could include the body of your existing template in place of the second variable, and have `<xsl:value-of select="$previous + ($numeric-value * $scaling-factor)" />` at the bottom; that's entirely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also go with a template function and `xsl:call-template`. Stealing @Dimitre input example (don't hate me :) I show you how you can use your conversion template rule with `xsl:call-template`.

In the transform I iterate on each `table-column` thus gathering the converted values. To convert the value I'm just calling your original template rule (a bit tuned). Then I use `sum` to perform the sum of the values.

Note that an XSLT 2.0 compliant processor will return a runtime error if you don't cast the value returned by `translate` to a number.

---

**XSLT 2.0** tested under **Saxon-B 9.0.0.4J**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="some:fo">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="fo:table/fo:table-column">

        <xsl:variable name="twips">
            <twips>
                <xsl:for-each select="preceding-sibling::fo:table-column/@column-width">
                    <twip>
                        <xsl:call-template name="convert-to-twips">
                            <xsl:with-param name="value" select="."/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </twip>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <twip>
                        <xsl:call-template name="convert-to-twips">
                            <xsl:with-param name="value" select="@column-width"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                </twip>
            </twips>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:value-of select="sum($twips//twip)"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="convert-to-twips">

        <xsl:param name="value"/>

        <xsl:variable name="scaling-factor">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains ($value, 'pt')">19.95</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains ($value, 'px')">15</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains ($value, 'pc')">240</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains ($value, 'in')">1440</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains ($value, 'cm')">567</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains ($value, 'mm')">56.7</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains ($value, 'em')">240</xsl:when>
                <!-- guess: 1em = 12pt -->
                <xsl:otherwise>1</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="numeric-value"
            select="number(translate ($value, '-0123456789.ptxcinme', '-0123456789.'))"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$numeric-value * $scaling-factor"/>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This transform applied on the input:

```
<fo:fo xmlns:fo="some:fo">
 <fo:table>
  <fo:table-column column-width="2pt"/>
  <fo:table-column column-width="2in"/>
  <fo:table-column column-width="2cm"/>
  <fo:table-column column-width="2mm"/>
  <fo:table-column column-width="2em"/>
  <fo:table-column column-width="2px"/>
  <fo:table-column column-width="2pc"/>
 </fo:table>
</fo:fo>
```

Produces:

```
39.9 2919.9 4053.9 4167.3 4647.3 4677.3 5157.3
```